# Any accounting Software especially coded for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any accounting application/software(`medium to large scale enterprise level`) especially coded for ubuntu.

Comment: this link should help you: http://www.aaxnet.com/design/linuxacct.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is ADempiere. It is a full ERP system.

http://www.adempiere.com/ADempiere_ERP

Comment: I'm going to try install under ubuntu and check this ERP package.

Answer (score 1):

In the repositories you'll also find: [ledgersmb](http://ledgersmb.org), [openerp](https://www.openerp.com/en/), and [tryton](http://www.tryton.org/).
Found through a basic search in the terminal: "apt-cache search financial accounting".

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy and best accounting, inventory and billing software then you should check this one.

[www.manager.io](http://www.manager.io)

And if you want completely free and best ERP system then you should try this below..

[www.xtuple.org](http://www.xtuple.org)